# "Must declare scalar variable" error

Tags: c#, sql-server

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Id"

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionstring");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT Goal from Planning WHERE Id = @Id");
int goal = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is the first line your error message?

Comment: yeah it is my first error message

Comment: BTW, your _connection string_ seems also wrong. If your `connectionstring` is a _variable_, you should use it like `new SqlConnection(connectionstring)` instead of `new SqlConnection(@"connectionstring")`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you declared your `Id` parameter in your `SqlCommand` but you didn't add it any value.

And you don't need to use `()` when you assing a text in your [`CommandText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Goal from Planning WHERE Id = @Id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", YourIdValue);
int goal = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

Here a complete example;

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
     cmd.Connection = con;
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Goal from Planning WHERE Id = @Id";
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", YourIdValue);
     try
     {
         conn.Open();
         int goal = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should give a value to your parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", value);
```

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)