# Must declare scalar variable @Id?

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I'm trying to get my "Customers" from my database, but i get an exception

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable `"@Id"`.

```
    using Core;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace DatabaseAccess
    {
        public class DbCustomer
        {
            private string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ConnectionString;
            private SqlConnection connection { get; set; }

            public DbCustomer()
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            }

            public Customer GetCustomer(int Id)
            {
                Customer customer = null;
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Id = @Id;";
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        customer = new Customer();
                        customer.Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id"));
                        customer.FirstName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName"));
                        customer.LastName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("LastName"));
                        customer.Address = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Address"));
                    }
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
                return customer;
            }
        }
    }

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Customer
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    }
}

using Core;
using DatabaseAccess;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public class CustomerController
    {
        public DbCustomer DbCustomer { get; set; }

        public CustomerController()
        {
            DbCustomer = new DbCustomer();
        }

        public Customer GetCustomer(int Id)
        {
            return DbCustomer.GetCustomer(Id);
        }
    }
}


using BusinessLogic;
using Core;
using DatabaseAccess;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WCF
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
    {
        CustomerController CustomerController = new CustomerController();

        public Customer GetCustomer(int Id)
        {
            return CustomerController.GetCustomer(Id);
        }

        public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            return new List<Customer>();
        }
    }
}

using Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCF
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICustomerService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Customer GetCustomer(int Id);

        [OperationContract]
        List<Customer> GetCustomers();

    }
}
```

Comment: Parameter need to pass some where right?

Comment: You set the parameter @id but you never assign a value. Therefore the compiler gives you this exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Must declare scalar variable" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646877/must-declare-scalar-variable-error)

Comment: Here is a good read about practices with TSQL http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-best-practices-part-1  I add this because of your "SELECT * "  avoid using * its not good practice.

Comment: Oh yeah I know that, my teacher told us many times, but It was just for testing purposes :) thank you though

Comment: @NeerajKumar I feel this question is a better question and has better answers already, I closed the other question and pointed it here. (Yes, it is fine to close older questions and point them at newer ones if the newer one is better)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain well if it has been closed then it is good to point them at newer ones. I agreed. when i checked it was not closed so I raised flag.

Comment: What's the point of calling `command.ExecuteNonQuery` just before you close the connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a `SqlParameter` with the name `@Id`

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Id = @Id;";
command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int32).Value = Id;
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to actually pass in a parameter:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Id = @Id;";
command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Id;
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Weird watching this particular post getting up and down voted... seems kind of rigged.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Adjusted

Comment: Wow.. I actually did use AddWithValue before but got another error, now it works, thank you so much

Comment: @Kixoka there are no downvotes on this answer (people with high rep can see total up and down votes). However some people may have removed upvotes and gave them to Jamiec because orginally this had `AddWithValue` and Jamiec did not.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Id ={id}";
```