# ASP.NET C# error Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I declared already so why do I get an error?

```
conn.Open();
String strCount = "Select SUM(freight) AS TOTAL from Orders where EmployeeID = @employee AND Year(OrderDate)= @Oyear";
SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand(strCount, conn);

cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Oyear", RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString());

double intCount = (double)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
Label1.Text = intCount.ToString();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: What is the name of your command object? `cmdCount`  or `cmdSelect` ?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: no use .AddWithValue() we can use what method to slove?

Comment: It is **clearly explained** in that post - read it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must declare scalar variable @Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771791/must-declare-scalar-variable-id)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the parameters to the wrong command.

Change the command name you add the parameters to, and it will work:

```
cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Oyear", RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```