# Must declare the scalar variable "@ManagerID"

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error

I have a Running Time Error: 
Must declare the scalar variable \"@ManagerID
I'm Sure I Have Declare All Variables In My CLass And My Procudure
My Class Code:

```
public DataTable Select(int ID,string NameFa, string Address, int ManagerID, short TotalUnits, int ChargeMethodID)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("NameFa", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("ManagerID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("TotalUnits", typeof(short));
    table.Columns.Add("ChargeMethodID", typeof(int));

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.SelectBuilding", con);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", ID));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NameFa", NameFa));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Address", Address));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ManagerID", ManagerID));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TotalUnits", TotalUnits));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChargeMethodID", ChargeMethodID));
         SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(table);
        return table;
    }
```

And My Procudure Code Is:

```
@ID int,
@NameFa nvarchar(150),
@Address nvarchar(MAX),
@ManagerID int,
@TotalUnits smallint,
@ChargeMethodID int
As
    Begin
        IF(@ID >0 )
            Begin
               Select ID,NameFa,Address,ManagerID,TotalUnits,ChargeMethodID From Buildings where ID = @ID
            End
        ELSE
            Begin
                Declare @sqlTxt nvarchar(MAX)
                SET @sqlTxt = 'SELECT ID,NameFa,Address,ManagerID,TotalUnits,ChargeMethodID FROM Buildings where ID>0'
                IF(@NameFa!= null)
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlTxt = @sqlTxt + ' AND NameFa Like ''%@NameFa%'''
                END
                IF(@Address!= null)
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlTxt = @sqlTxt + ' AND Address Like ''%@Address%'''
                END
                IF(@ManagerID > 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlTxt = @sqlTxt + ' AND ManagerID = @ManagerID'
                END
                IF(@TotalUnits > 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlTxt = @sqlTxt + ' AND TotalUnits = @TotalUnits'
                END
                IF(@ChargeMethodID > 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @sqlTxt = @sqlTxt + ' AND ChargeMethodID = @ChargeMethodID'
                END
                EXEC (@sqlTxt);
            End
    END
```

And I want to use Select Function:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Buildings.Building bb = new Buildings.Building() {ID=0,NameFa="",Address="",ManagerID=OwnerID,TotalUnits=0,ChargeMethodID=0 };
    dt = bu.Select(bb.ID,bb.NameFa,bb.Address,bb.ManagerID,bb.TotalUnits,bb.ChargeMethodID);
```

Comment: What's the value of OwnerID at runtime?

Comment: `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details`.?

Comment: With This Value Buildings Excists I Test In Sqlserver But It Dont Run In Procudure

Comment: SQL Injetion warning alert. Unless you trust every posible user that executes your stored procedure, you should not use exec to run the SQL statement. I am gonna edi my answer tu suggest a better aproach

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Must declare scalar variable" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646877/must-declare-scalar-variable-error)

Comment: Dit you even [Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=must+declare+scalar+variable+c%23+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=must+declare+scalar+variable+c%23+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1740.2060.0.2284.4.4.0.0.0.0.132.250.3j1.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.YMjcV2-4yds)?

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the parameters to the exec statement. I would change it to `sp_executesql` which has an optional argument with parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Edit: I strongly suggest getting rid of the `exec` and/or `sp_executesql` commands. Because depending on the input you could:

a) Get runtime errors due to user typing SQL string delimiters as a valid input. Example O'Hara as a surname.

b) A malicious user could mess badly with your database.

You could get similar result in a more simple way:

```
Select 
    ID,NameFa,Address,ManagerID,TotalUnits,ChargeMethodID 
From 
    Buildings
 where
    (@Id = 0 or ID = @Id)
    and (@NameFa = '' or NameFa = @NameFa)
    and (@ManagerID = 0 or ManagerID = @ManagerID)
    // repeat for the rest of the optional search conditions
```